# How to properly align questions, parts, and subparts in Latex Exam class

Tags: overleaf, templates, exam

I want to create the following setup in an exam paper. Table borders will be removed before print.

[image]

I used the following Latex code to generate similar setup in Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\marksnotpoints
\pointformat{\quad[\textbf{\thepoints}]}
\pointsinrightmargin
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{25mm}

\qformat{\textbf{Q\thequestion\hfill[Total: \thepoints]}}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{35pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[100]%

\begin{parts}

\part[50]
Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a Part a
\begin{subparts}
    \subpart Sub part i
    \subpart Sub part ii
\end{subparts}

\part[50]
\begin{subparts}
    \subpart Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i Sub part i
    \subpart Sub part ii
\end{subparts}

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I got the following in Latex after compiling.

[image]

How may I correct the following alignment issues?

1. In line 1 (total is not properly aligned with rest of the marks)
2. Subparts are not aligned properly in part b.
3. 2nd line in part a is not aligned with line 1 properly.
4. How to avoid questions extending to the marks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!